# Display series of tables one by one JS

Tags: jquery

I want to display a series of tables that are generated by AJAX.

Below is my JS code.

```
$(function() {
    $(".buttonTEST").on("click",function(e) {
        $(".18").toggle( "slow", function showNext() {  
            $(this).toggle("slow");
            $(this).next("table").toggle( "slow", showNext);    
        });
    });
});
```

18 is the class of the first table.
The code works fine but displays the table and closes them WAT too fast.
What i want is some pause between the open-close and the next open-close.
I tried playing around with `setTimeout` but kept ending up with never ending loops and errors.

How can i do this?

Comment: 12345 works fine but what if i want to pause between a change ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.slowToggle = function() {
    item = $(this);        
    item.toggle("slow", function() {                        
        setTimeout(function(){
           var next = item.next("table");
           if(next.length) {
               next.slowToggle();
           } else {
              return null;
           }
        }, 2000);
    });
}

$(".buttonTEST").on("click",function(e) {
    $(".18").slowToggle();            
});
```

Here's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vfdqe/2/)

Comment: as i mentioned above tables are being displayed fine except that they are closed and opened way too fast. How can i implement a "pause" between changes?

Comment: Keeping things as DRY as i could, i made changes you need. What baffles me though, is that unless i wrap `toggleNext` inside a function, this code won't work. I don't know any reasons for this, and it may be a valid SO question itself :)

Comment: Edited once again. This time no weird wrappers.